# Change CPU Clock Speed from Windows

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-speed

How can I change the CPU clock speed of my computer? It is a Dell Inspiron 5720 laptop, running Windows 8.1 Pro. In Linux, I know there are ways of doing this from the operating system itself, instead of having to go through the BIOS, like [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/indicator-cpufreq-cpu-frequency-scaling-indicator-applet) and [this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils). Is this possible in Windows?

Comment: I've only seen it done with apps from the mobo vendor, but that doesn't mean it cant be done from commandline using some utility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can achieve lower frequencies from power options menu:

[image]

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmgBz.png)

Setting maximum and minimum processor state to some percentage will probably fix the frequency on some level depending on your maximum CPU frequency.

However, this appears not to be under-clocking. [A more detailed answer](https://superuser.com/a/688074/279815) explains this in depth.